# model not recognizing current_user or User.current in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

As the title states, all my other models are able to recognize User.current in my models but in one of my new models I'm trying to do the following and can't get it working. Actually I think it does work but it states it doesn't have that column. Column is there in the User and I can access it through the Rails Console if I assign the user. User gets authenticated using devise right too. Here's my code in my Model;

MODEL

```
def self.something

    user = User.current
    if user.oauth.blank?

    else 

    end

end
```

I'm trying to think whats wrong and have no clue. I'm guessing I can pass that from the controller like so;

CONTROLLER

```
def index
   Model.something(current_user)
end
```

MODEL

```
def self.something(current_user)

   user = current_user
   if user.oauth.blank?

   end

end
```

Haven't tested it, maybe it won't work that way either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_user` is a controller helper and will not be available in the model. In fact, trying to use it within the model is a violation of the model-view-controller structure that Rails uses. While there may be hacks to allow this to work, I highly recommend finding an alternate solution to your problem.

For instance, if your model always expects `current_user` to contain the currently-logged-in user, what user should be used when Rails is running at the console? What about a rake task?

The correct method here is to pass current_user from the controller to the model, as you're doing in your code example, always. This means that any controller action that *may* end up needing to know the current user should have it included. In my projects I will always pass the current user within the context of the controller's action. An example:

```
class ThingsController
  def update
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    if @thing.update_attributes(thing_attributes_for_update)
      # Redirect with flash message
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def thing_attributes_for_update
    params[:thing].slice(%w(first_name last_name).merge({'updater' => current_user})
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, if you're creating new records instead of updating, always use ActiveRecord's relationship methods to do this, instead of building heavy logic within your model. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5016013/1589422